# Get all the books By Author - in Dictionary object(Dictionary<AuthorName, List<Book>>)

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

How to get all the books By Author - in Dictionary object.
(Dictionary>)

```
List<Book> authors = new List<Book>      
{  
   new Book{ AuthorName = " Chand", Book = "xyz", Price = 49 },      
   new Book{ AuthorName = "Neel ", Book = "abc", Price = 19 },      
   new Book{ AuthorName = "chetan", Book = "zxe", Price = 29 }      
};
```

Without using LINQ perform the below operation on List of Books

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use LINQ?

Comment: Where is `Dictionary` object? Do you want the result to be one?

Comment: So basically, you want to go through all items of the list of books, check, if you already have an entry in the dictionary for the author of the book and add the book to the list of books specific to that author? Have you already made an attempt at doing this?

Comment: why are you  want to use Dictionary ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var booksByAuthors = new Dictionary<string, List<Book>>();

foreach (var author in authors)
{
    if (booksByAuthors.ContainsKey(author.AuthorName))
        booksByAuthors[author.AuthorName].Add(author);
    else
        booksByAuthors.Add(author.AuthorName, new List<Book>{author});
}
```

Comment: What type does AuthorName property have?